# CAN BUS circuit using arduino and STM32 not receiving data

Tags: arduino, can, arduino-uno

I tried to connect arduino uno R3 to STM32 using MCP2515 CAN bus transceiver. This was the transmitter code:

```
#include <SPI.h> //Library for using SPI Communication
#include <mcp2515.h> //Library for using CAN Communication



struct can_frame canMsg;
MCP2515 mcp2515(10);

void setup(){
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin(); //Begins SPI communication
  
  mcp2515.reset();
  mcp2515.setBitrate(CAN_500KBPS, MCP_16MHZ); //Sets CAN at speed 500KBPS and Clock 8MHz
  mcp2515.setNormalMode();
}

void loop(){
  
  canMsg.can_id = 0x036; //CAN id as 0x036
  canMsg.can_dlc = 8; //CAN data length as 8
  canMsg.data[0] = 0x04; //Update humidity value in [0]
  canMsg.data[1] = 0x03; //Update temperature value in [1]
  canMsg.data[2] = 0x02; //Rest all with 0
  canMsg.data[3] = 0x01;
  canMsg.data[4] = 0x00;
  canMsg.data[5] = 0x00;
  canMsg.data[6] = 0x00;
  canMsg.data[7] = 0x00;
  mcp2515.sendMessage(&canMsg); //Sends the CAN message
  Serial.println("Sent")  ;
  
  delay(1000);
}
```

And the receiver code was

```
#include <SPI.h> //Library for using SPI Communication
#include <mcp2515.h> //Library for using CAN Communication

struct can_frame canMsg;
MCP2515 mcp2515(10); // SPI CS Pin 10

void setup() {
  SPI.begin();   //Begins SPI communication
  Serial.begin(9600); //Begins Serial Communication at 9600 baud rate
  mcp2515.reset();
  mcp2515.setBitrate(CAN_500KBPS,MCP_16MHZ); //Sets CAN at speed 500KBPS and Clock 8MHz
  mcp2515.setNormalMode();  //Sets CAN at normal mode
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println(mcp2515.readMessage(&canMsg));
  delay(1000);
 if ((mcp2515.readMessage(&canMsg) == MCP2515::ERROR_OK) && (canMsg.can_id == 0x036)){
     int x = canMsg.data[0];
     int y = canMsg.data[1];
     
     Serial.print(x);
     
     Serial.println(y);
     
     
   }
}
```

I found out that "Sent" was printed properly while the message was not received on the other end. I tried to print mcp2515.readMessage(&canMsg) which was found to be 5. What's going wrong?
Some image of my setup:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are the 120 Ohm termination resistors?

Comment: OK, so what does the return value of 5 mean? If you have two devices on the bus that are otherwise isolated, don't you need a common ground reference between the devices?

Comment: @Justme We dont know what does 5 mean. Can u please elaborate the 2nd Q?

Comment: @Jeroen3 the can transceiver has 120 ohm termination resistor

Comment: What is the name of the board assembly with MCP2515? Would you post the link to datasheet of the board?

Comment: @Helixxxx Exactly that is my question, if you use a library, surely there must be some way of figuring out what the return code of 5 means - there must be documentation, instructions, or at least the source code to look at - unless you got a binary library without documentation how to use it. The termination resistor, while it exists on board, it is not enabled, on either of the boards. Do you have a ground connection between the MCU or CAN boards via some route, like are they powered from same laptop?

Comment: @jay This the link for the CAN bus:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj_h8XNxt_yAhXbwTgGHZNpBPEQFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fww1.microchip.com%2Fdownloads%2Fen%2FDeviceDoc%2FMCP2515-Stand-Alone-CAN-Controller-with-SPI-20001801J.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2Vloea2cjAmo_0e_ZDOV2e

Comment: @Justme Yes i have documentation, but I'm not so familiar with the source code (I don't understand them) for the library. Sure, I will try to look deeper now. And yes.. they are connected to the same laptop.

Comment: @Helixxxx The what does the documentation say about return values for that function? Also you link to the datasheet of the CAN contoroller chip which is irrelevant here, you need the documentation of the PCB module to know how to use the module properly.

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://protosupplies.com/product/mcp2515-can-bus-interface-module/   https://github.com/coryjfowler/MCP_CAN_lib

Comment: Is the jumper placed between H & L ? Don't see well ...

Comment: Thanks @Antonio51. Helix, you need to populate a jumper on J1. Schematic is [here](https://protosupplies.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/MCP2515-CAN-Bus-Module-Schematic.jpg). No jumper on J3, keep it open.

Comment: thank you so much guys

Comment: [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251) And as mentioned in that link you should be using external quartz for MCU clocks, given that the ST board got a built-in CAN controller. There's a slot for a crystal on that board but none is mounted, so you are using internal oscillators with low resolution.

Comment: @Lundin Should Arduino also have the same? I'm not really getting how it STMs built-in CAN controller linked to the external oscillator (or quartz).